# Do the english user translate "monk making it his object to let go" as "monk knowing nibbāna", right?

Tags: pali-canon, pali, translation

I ask this question because in pali, "to let go (nibbāna)", in this context, is known by monk. It is not just a target. The (ariya) monk thinking of nibbāna in his concentration, in this context.

I just wanna make sure that english translation is right, because when I translate that english sentence, by my terrible english, it look like "to let go " and "object" means "target", not "something is known by monk".

In the pāli: **ārammaṇa** means "something is known by consciousness", "something is thought by consciousness", **"external sense-fields"**. It doesn't means **target/object**.

> "And what is the faculty of concentration? There is the case where a monk, a disciple of the noble ones, **making it his object to let go**, attains concentration, attains singleness of mind. 
>   http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn48/sn48.010.than.html

---

Edited:

It should to be:

> "And what is the faculty of concentration? There is the case where a monk, a disciple of the noble ones, **making "to let go" as his mind's focus**, attains concentration, attains singleness of mind.

Comment: It seems to be not clear what Nyom Warapol tries to ask, but maybe there are some who can follow his current *ārammaṇa*. Maybe worthy to point out the point another time.

Comment: I have asked, so I asking here again, because they gave me 2 answers that are not the same: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/143659/why-making-it-his-object-to-let-go-translated-as-making-to-letting-go-to-be-h

Comment: Maybe it's general good to know that what is meant by *ārammaṇa*, western use consciousness or awareness for it. So its general not easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**it look like "to let go " and "object" means "target", not "something is known by monk".**

Yes, I think the English is a bit ambiguous, and it could be understood to mean either (or both).

The word "object" has many meanings, [of which two are](https://www.google.fr/search?q=define%3Aobject):

> - a person or thing to which a specified action or feeling is directed.
>     "disease became the object of investigation"
>     *synonyms*: target, butt, focus, recipient, victim
>     "he became the object of fierce criticism"
> - a goal or purpose.
>     "the Institute was opened with the object of promoting scientific study"
>     *synonyms*: purpose, objective, aim, goal, target, end, end in view, plan, object of the exercise

So an English reader might understand it as the *focus* of meditation (what you're attentive to), or as the *purpose* of meditation (what your aim or ambition is).

Comment: "Focus" is obviously better than "object". Thank you very much.

Comment: Focus is the opposite of letting go because letting go is making the mind "open & expansive" and focus is making the mind narrow.

Comment: @Dhammadhatu Is there a (single- or multi-word) translation you prefer instead of "focus"?

Comment: "Target" is also wrong because "target" is craving (tanha). BonnWarapol is attempting to distort the transmission of lokuttara meditation practice and replace it with worldly yogic meditation. The instruction in SN 48.10 is making vossaggo the sense object or pre-occupation of the mind. "Vossagga" means "giving up" targets, goals & ambitions.

Comment: Taking object in it's second meaning here, is fine "objective". Focus is a synomym of concentration. But the main point here is maybe that Nyom Warapol likes to point out, that Nibbana in this case is not just an idea but know, is that right?

Comment: @SamanaJohann Yes the main point is that he's saying that *ārammaṇa* means "known, a sense-object" (and maybe not "just an idea" or a not-yet-attained target) -- although, as to 'what' is known, the sutta says *Vossagga* not *Nibbana*.

Comment: @ChrisW 'what' is known, the sutta says "vossaggārammaṇaṃ (ārammaṇa that is called vossagga)". It is avadhāraṇa-samāsa in pali-language.

Comment: @ChrisW In āpaṇasutta said paññindriya thinking of nibbāna, so vossaggārammaṇa of concentration in the same context must have the same thinking, too. Therefore commentary translate vossagga as nibbāna. It is because of āpaṇasutta, https://suttacentral.net/pi/sn48.50.

Answer (score 1):

Let my person give an answer that might be releasing in many ways :-)

> **[Carrying a Rock](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/thai/chah/insimpleterms_en.html)**
>
> "Letting go" actually means this: It's as if we're carrying a heavy rock. As we carry it, we feel weighed down but we don't know what to do with it, so we keep on carrying it. As soon as someone tells us to throw it away, we think, "Eh? If I throw it away, I won't have anything left." So we keep on carrying it. We aren't willing to throw it away.
>
> Even if someone tells us, "Come on. Throw it away. It'll be good like this, and you'll benefit like that," we're still not willing to throw it away because we're afraid we won't have anything left. So we keep on carrying it until we're so thoroughly weak and tired that we can't carry it anymore. That's when we let it go.
>
> Only when we let it go do we understand letting go. We feel at ease. And we can sense within ourselves how heavy it felt to carry the rock. But while we were carrying it, we didn't know at all how useful letting go could be.

One might fear to try it, but than it's known, possible to make it a valide direct perception again.

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma, not meant for commercial purpose or other low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange, directed to Nibbana, to simply let go]*

Answer (score 0):

"having made release the object"... Bhikkhu Bodhi

[image]

---

Idha, bhikkhave, ariyasāvako, **vossaggārammaṇaṁ** karitvā, labhati samādhiṁ

Here, monks, a noble disciple, having **relinquished sense objects**, attains concentration,

Ānandajoti Bhikkhu

Comment: I asking for an english translation's meaning. I can translate pali and I can read thai. I have no doubt about the pali or thai meaning. Also, you copy wrong quote. It should be above paragraph of your quote.

Comment: This answer is out of topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you want 'purpose'?

"*And what is the faculty of concentration? Consider where a monk, a disciple of the noble ones, chooses "letting go" as his purpose, whereby he attains concentration and attains singleness of mind.*"

Maybe I am missing something, but in order to let go, you must also remain vigilant to whether or not you remain in a state of letting go. Therefore, and regardless, letting go is a valid object of concentration.